# Highcharts and Java: saving image on server side

Tags: java, jquery, highcharts

I'm trying to save a Highcharts charts as png image on server side. I found [this link](http://www.blog.openshell.in/2014/08/how-to-save-an-image-of-the-highcharts-on-the-server/) where it shows how to use jQuery to submit the image as a string, and php to generate the file. I'm trying to replace php with a Java servlet on the server side.

The servlet receives the string and the image file is generated with 47K but it is blank.

Is the servlet converting the string correctly? `System.out.println` is showing the string as submitted by the client.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    String strFile = request.getParameter("bin_data");
    strFile.replace(' ', '+');
    System.out.println("***"+strFile);
    byte[] decoded = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(strFile);
    try (OutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream("d:/abc.png")) {
        stream.write(decoded);
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

This is the jQuery on the client side that submits the image string:

```
    $("#save_img").click(function(){
        var svg = chart.getSVG(); 
        canvg(document.getElementById('canvas'),svg);
        var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png"); //img is data:image/png;base64
        img = img.replace('data:image/png;base64,', '');
        var data = "bin_data=" + img;
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "/storeimg",  // this is the servlet url
          data: data,
          success: function(data){
            alert('success');
          }
        });
    });
```

where chart is

```
chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    ....
    ....
});
```

UPDATE: code works well with fix described in the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was that

```
strFile.replace(' ', '+');
```

needed to be

```
strFile = strFile.replace(' ', '+');
```

This is needed as posting the string will convert '+' characters to spaces.

The code works well now, I'm able to save Highchart charts in png files on the server side

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this line:

```
byte[] decoded = Base64.decodeBase64(strFile);
```

If you are sending the full image as request:

```
   boolean isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);
   System.out.println("request: "+request);
   if (!isMultipart) {
          System.out.println("File Not Uploaded");
   } else {
          FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
          ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
          List items = null;

          try {
               items = upload.parseRequest(request);
               System.out.println("items: "+items);
          } catch (FileUploadException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
          }
   }
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's not a file upload, the image is contained in a string

Comment: Ops, my fault sorry. But when you debbug it, is the string empty, or is there a lot of characteres?

Comment: The string is not empty, it contains the same data as submitted from the client side. The png file is generated with 47K, but when you open it, it's blank. The dimensions (height and width) are correct, though.

Comment: Ok, that seems good tho. try using byte[] decoded = Base64.decodeBase64(strFile);

Comment: I used `Base64.decodeBase6` and get the same result; it seems that the problem is not in decoding the string as both functions (`decodeBase64` and `parseBase64Binary`) return the same byte[] array.